# writing a custom rails attribute validator that depends on another attribute being valid

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm using the awesome [client_side_validations](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations) gem and I've written a custom validator like this:

```
class PersonNameValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attr_name, value)
    record.errors.add(attr_name) if record.errors.has_key?(:person_id)
  end
end
```

My goal is to have the virtual attribute `:person_name` be invalid if `:person_id` is invalid.  My question is whether it is reasonable to use `if record.errors.has_key?` **inside another validator** as a way to determine if another attribute is valid?

I read that validators fire in the order declared so this is in my model:

```
validates :person_id, numericality: { greater_than: 0 }
validates :person_name, presence: true
```

Is it wise to rely on this technique as a way to keep my validations DRY?

Comment: updated since i should be using `record.errors.has_key?`